# Is there a way to move taskbar items to the system tray?

Tags: windows-xp, notification-area

In Windows XP, is there a utility that will let me move taskbar items to the system tray? I've seen "minimize to tray" type utilities but I'm talking about for maximized applications.

Comment: All I can find is minimize to try, wouldn't it help to have it for each non-focused screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might '4t Tray Minimizer' be what you are looking for?

It doesn't actually move items to your tray, but 'hides' them from the task bar....
Good for cygwin X11 process that you dont really want in your taskbar,
but dont need in your system tray either.

Other options (but not tried them out) could be:

- 4t Tray Minimizer
- PowerMenu (mentioned above with nice screenshot)
- WinRoll
- RBTray
- TrayEverything
- TrayIt
- Trayconizer
- TaskSwitchXP

I haven't the links, but google ought to help out.
Maybe this should be a community wiki post? (once I ever figure out just what that means)

Comment: TrayEverything is no good. I just try it. PowerMenu is not working with Win7. 4t Tray Minimizer is ok (a bit slow though).

Answer (score 3):

[PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/) is a small application I wrote back in 1998 to add some extra menu items to the windows control menu in addition to the standard "Close", "Maximize", etc options. The extra menus are: Always On Top, Transparency and Minimize To Tray.

[image]

[image]

I couldn't find anything (yet) that makes them stay in the tray, but as long as only your active application is on your taskbar, this should trim down the size a lot. If I find anything better I'll update my post.

Comment: Funny enough Linux DOES have some tools to do this...

Comment: Any chance of a 64Bit version?

Comment: There were a lot of comments on his blog asking for it, can't find one though

Comment: I used to love that program but now it doesn't work with Win 7.